# Autobahn VS Einaros - Websockets with Node JS

Tags: node.js, autobahn

I need to write a WebSocket server and I am learning Node JS by reading some books I purchased. This server is for a very fast game so I need to stream small messages to groups of clients as quick as possible.

What is the difference between:

> Autobahn | JS : http://autobahn.ws/js/

and

> Einaros : https://github.com/einaros/ws

?

I have heard that Autobahn is very powerful and capable to deal with 200k clients without a load balancer so I was wondering if someone with more experience could advise me whether there is any advantage in opting for one or another library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functional difference is: Einaros is a WebSocket library, whereas Autobahn provides WebSocket implementations (e.g. [AutobahnPython](http://autobahn.ws/python/)), plus WAMP on top of WebSocket.

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) provides higher-level communication for apps (RPC + PubSub - pls see the WAMP website). And AutobahnJS is a WAMP implementation for browsers (and NodeJS) *on top of WebSocket*.

Now, say you don't care about WAMP, and hence only need a raw WebSocket server. Then you can compare AutobahnPython with Einaros primarily based on non-functional characteristics, like protocol compliance, security and performance.

Autobahn has best-in-class protocol compliance. I dare to say that, since the Autobahn project also provides the quasi industry standard WebSocket [testsuite](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/) - used by most projects - including Einaros. Autobahn has 100% strict passes on all tests. Einaros *probably* also - I don't know.

Performance: yes, a single AutobahnPython based WebSocket server (4GB RAM, 2 cores, PyPy, FreeBSD in a VirtualBox VM) can handle 200k connected clients. To give you some more data points: here is a [post](http://tavendo.com/blog/post/autobahn-pi-benchmark/) with performance benchmarks on the RaspberryPi.

In particular, this post highlights the most important (IMO) metric: 95%/99% quantile messaging latency. You shouldn't look only at average latency, since there can be big skews and massive outliers. What you want is *consistent* low latency.

Achieving consistent low latency is non-trivial. E.g. one factor for languages/run-times like NodeJS or [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) (a JITted Python implementation) is the garbage collector. Every time the GC runs, it'll slow stuff done - potentially introducing large latencies in messaging. I have done extensive benchmarking (unpublished) which indicates that PyPy's incremental GC is *very* good in this regard. Better than HotSpot (JVM) and NodeJS (Google V8). When in doubt, and since I haven't (yet) published numbers, you shouldn't believe me, but measure yourself.

The one thing I'd strongly recommend: don't rely on average latency, measure quantiles, do histograms.

Disclose: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.